# COM error in downloading attachment from outlook through win32com

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

```
import win32com.client

import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items

message = messages.GetFirst()

attachments = message.Attachments

for i in messages:

    if(i.UnRead==True):

        attachment = attachments.Item(1) 

        attachment.SaveASFile(os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(attachment))

    else:

        pass
```

I am getting below error when trying to download the attachment from outlook

```
Error: com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Array index out of bounds.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

Comment: Use a Debugger or add some print statements to find the line where the exception is thrown. You are using an invalid index to access an array. Update the `attachments` variable within the loop and check the `Items.Count` to avoid invalid array access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code assumes every message in the Inbox folder has at least one attachment. That assumption is clearly invalid.

Either check that `Attachments.Count > 0` or actually loop over the attachments collection instead of simply retrieving the very first attachment (`attachments.Item(1)`) whether the message has attachments or nor.

Also keep in mind `messages.GetFirst()` will return some random item since you never sort the collection in any way. Most likely you will get the oldest created message. Do not assume that the sort order of the messages shown by Outlook will be the same as what you have.

Comment: Thank you all for assistance, I am able to run the code without any issue